# Postgresql and big multidimensional arrays

Tags: arrays, postgresql, matlab, multidimensional-array

i used to work with mysql and save my huge 3 dimensional arrays as blob files 
but now i'm using postgresql and it looks like it supports array datatype.
does any fast method exist to store those big arrays into the postgre database?
i mean each 3d array has to be saved in a single cell from the postgre table and not as a table.
Im working with Matlab, where the data is in under the form of 176x144x1750 Int arrays, and i can directly connect to the database from matlab and execute queries.
thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would use a three-dimensional array.
>
> For example: CREATE TABLE (   INTEGER
>   id PRIMARY KEY,   array INTEGER[][][]
>   );
>
> I think you will find more tips about
>   postgres muldimensional arrays in this
>   link
>   http://www.chsd.com.br/index.php?option=Article&action=Show&view=Article&id=3
>
> There is the PostgreSQL page too.
>   http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/arrays.html

Comment: Thanks, do you know what are the limits for arrays in Postgre?i mean the highest number of elements that an array can have.